# celery beat dynamically add task while calling API in flask python

Tags: python, flask, celery, scheduler, celerybeat

I am trying to schedule tasks to celery beat via flask API.

*http://0.0.0.0:9000/api/v1/add_task*

Flask API code:-

```
@app.route('/api/v1/add_task',methods=['POST'])
def setup_periodic_tasks():
   scheduler = request.json['scheduler']
   setup_celery_config(scheduler=scheduler)
   return "task added"

@celery.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_celery_config(**kwargs):
  print(kwargs.get("scheduler"))
  celery.add_periodic_task(10, myfunction.s(kwargs.get("scheduler")))

@celery.task 
def myfunction(scheduler):
  print(scheduler)
```

I run this python flask application in one terminal. Also, run celery worker & celery beat in the other two.

While calling this API, the setup_celery_config function will trigger twice. At first, it prints kwargs.get("scheduler") with exact scheduler value, and the second time it prints *Null*. add_periodic_task only trigger with second *Null* value. So the scheduler not added correctly.

Is there any problem with using "on_after_configure"..?
Please help me to solve this issue.....

Regards,
Gokul